# I want to show menu when cursor hovers over pushbutton and close menu when cursor is moved away

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt on Ubuntu.

I have a menu on `QPushButton`. I want to show menu when cursor hovers over the `QPushButton` and close menu when cursor is moved away.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, read this and adjust your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . You need to provide information about what you had tried (or a SSCCE) and clarify your question.

Answer (score 2):

Showing a popup menu on "hover" event seems to violate the user experience, as users expect to see the popup when they click the button. This is called a *menu button*. If you really want to use *hover* event, you may subclass the `QPushButton` class and use its respective events. However if you would like to use a *menu button*, you can try this:

```
QMenu *menu = new QMenu();
QAction *testAction = new QAction("test menu item", this);
menu->addAction(testAction);

button->setMenu(menu);
```

[image]

[Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html#setMenu) on `QPushButton::setMenu`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement your owen QPushButton. Let's start by checking the [MouseMoveEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.7/qwidget.html#mouseMoveEvent) to handle when the mouse hover the widget.

To check if the cursos pos is inside your widget:

```
void CustomPushButton::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e) {
    const QRect widgetRect = ui->followersWidget->geometry();
    const QPoint mousePos = ui->followersWidget->mapFromGlobal(QCursor::pos()); // or e->pos()
    if (widgetRect.contains(mousePos)) {
        // Mouse inside the widget, lets show the menu
    } else {
       // Mouse outside the widget, if the menu is open, close it.
    }
    QWidget::mousePressEvent(e);
}
```

To show/hide the menu you could use the [QMenu::popup(..)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmenu.html#popup), from Qt Doc:

> Displays the menu so that the action atAction will be at the specified global position p. To translate a widget's local coordinates into global coordinates, use QWidget::mapToGlobal().

Comment: I am new to Qt and c++ can u please tell me where do i put this code? I have a class SimplePlayer. my pushbutton name is ui->user.

Comment: You have to customize your own QPushButton a subclass of QWidget and reimplement the protected virtual function void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *e).  See: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1405227&seqNum=2 for more detail.

Comment: I would expect you need to reimplement mouseMoveEvent, not mousePressEvent